# Как обрезать часть изображения с соотношением?

Tags: php

Как обрезать часть изображения? Если **Максимальный размер = Оригинальный размер** работает нормально, а так не работает :(

Оригинальный размер фото **300x423px**
Максимальный размер (Размер фото для обрезка) **213x300px**

```
$filename = '/test.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$width = 213;
$height = 213;
$new_width = 200;
$new_height = 200;
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumb, null, 90);
```

Фотографии до и после обрезки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фотографии должно быть таким.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а этот код для этих размеров или левый взяли просто не можете цифры подставить нужные?

Comment: мне например не совсем понятно.. надо сначала уменьшить фото до максимальной ширины, а только затем его обрезать?

Comment: @Jean-Claude обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Так узнайте размер картинки сначала:

```
$size=getimagesize($filename)
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];
```

У вас размер загружаемого изображения прописан в коде, когда он должен быть получен из загруженного файла

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Спасибо я об этом знаю. Например если ширина 300px то x = 15, y = 15 а если ширина 213px то x = ?, y = ?. Разные фото, разные x, y (раздвиг)